# c# Dropbox download file by httpwebrequest

Tags: c#, dropbox, dropbox-api

I have an 'ASP.NET' console application and I use Dropbox API `https://content.dropboxapi.com/1/files/auto/<path> to download content from`
 I just have the `AppKey`, `AppSecret`, `Access Token`, `Token Secret` and the `path` of file.

How to send request with httpwebrequest.

Comment: It sounds like you're using OAuth 1. Take a look at https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2012/07/using-oauth-1-0-with-the-plaintext-signature-method/.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by an "ASP.NET console application?"

Comment: Open the [link](https://dzone.com/articles/what-aspnet-console) to understand "ASP.NET console application.

Comment: @smarx thank you for the link.I found the answer in the link https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2012/07/using-oauth-1-0-with-the-plaintext-signature-method/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I search in google and i found the best answer in [link](https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2012/07/using-oauth-1-0-with-the-plaintext-signature-method/):

```
 string url = String.Format("https://content.dropboxapi.com/1/files/auto{0}?oauth_consumer_key={1}&oauth_token={2}&oauth_signature={3}%26{4}", path, app-key, access-token, app-secret, access-token-secret);
 HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
 webRequest.Method = "Get";
 WebResponse webResponse = null;
  try
  {
     webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();
     return webResponse.GetResponseStream();
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    throw ex;       
  }
```